# Installl FTP and MySql tasks for Ant 1.8.2  on OSX

Tags: mysql, ant, ftp, continuous-integration, jenkins

I can't get either the FTP nor the MySQL Task working for `Ant 1.8.2` on `Mac OSX 10.7`.

I tried everything I found on this site and everything I found via Google.
It seems I need a `JDCB` Driver for the `MySQL` Task, but I don't get how to install or where to put it.
For the FTP Task ant commons library is needed, which I copied to lib folder of my ant installation.
The library is loaded as diagnostic mode says, but it is not working.

## Build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project name="Testjob" default="build">   <target name="build" depends="sql,ftp"/>

  <property name="sql.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>   <property name="sql.url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxx.de"/>   <property name="sql.user" value="xxx"/>   <property name="sql.pass" value="xxx"/>

  <target name="sql">
    <sql driver="${sql.driver}" 
      url="${sql.url}"
      userid="${sql.user}"
      password="${sql.pass}" >
      <transaction src="client.sql"/>
      <transaction src="project.sql"/>
    </sql>   </target>

  <target name="ftp" description="FTP">
    <ftp server="ftp.xxx.de"
          remotedir="incoming"
          userid="xxx"
          password="xxx"
          depends="yes">
      <fileset dir="*"/>
    </ftp>   </target> </project>
```

## FTP-Error

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Testjob/workspace/build.xml:25: Problem: failed to create task or type ftp
Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP was not found.
        This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
        -/usr/share/ant/lib
        -/var/root/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument

Do not panic, this is a common problem.
The commonest cause is a missing JAR.

This is not a bug; it is a configuration problem
```

## SQL-Error

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Testjob/workspace/build.xml:19: Class Not Found: JDBC driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver could not be loaded
```

## Diagnostics

```
 ------- Ant diagnostics report -------Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010

 -------------------------------------------  Implementation Version
 ------------------------------------------- core tasks     : 1.8.2 in file:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant.jar

 -------------------------------------------  ANT PROPERTIES
 ------------------------------------------- ant.version: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010 ant.java.version:
 1.6 Is this the Apache Harmony VM? no Is this the Kaffe VM? no Is this gij/gcj? no ant.core.lib: /Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant.jar
 ant.home: /Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant

 -------------------------------------------  ANT_HOME/lib jar listing
 ------------------------------------------- ant.home: /Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant ant-antlr.jar (5748 bytes)
 ant-apache-bcel.jar (8746 bytes) ant-apache-bsf.jar (3931 bytes)
 ant-apache-log4j.jar (3059 bytes) ant-apache-oro.jar (39638 bytes)
 ant-apache-regexp.jar (3761 bytes) ant-apache-resolver.jar (4084
 bytes) ant-apache-xalan2.jar (2295 bytes) ant-commons-logging.jar
 (3913 bytes) ant-commons-net-1.8.2.jar (85511 bytes)
 ant-commons-net.jar (85511 bytes) ant-jai.jar (22265 bytes)
 ant-javamail.jar (7960 bytes) ant-jdepend.jar (8222 bytes) ant-jmf.jar
 (6739 bytes) ant-jsch.jar (40175 bytes) ant-junit.jar (102220 bytes)
 ant-junit4.jar (7120 bytes) ant-launcher.jar (12322 bytes)
 ant-netrexx.jar (10392 bytes) ant-swing.jar (7555 bytes)
 ant-testutil.jar (15201 bytes) ant.jar (1933743 bytes)

 -------------------------------------------  USER_HOME/.ant/lib jar listing
 ------------------------------------------- user.home: /Users/alexanderfeil ant-commons-net-1.8.2.jar (85511 bytes)

 -------------------------------------------  Tasks availability
 ------------------------------------------- sshexec : Missing dependency com.jcraft.jsch.Logger wlrun : Not Available (the
 implementation class is not present) scp : Missing dependency
 com.jcraft.jsch.Logger stlist : Not Available (the implementation
 class is not present) sshsession : Missing dependency
 com.jcraft.jsch.Logger starteam : Not Available (the implementation
 class is not present) stlabel : Not Available (the implementation
 class is not present) jdepend : Missing dependency
 jdepend.xmlui.JDepend stcheckin : Not Available (the implementation
 class is not present) stcheckout : Not Available (the implementation
 class is not present) ejbc : Not Available (the implementation class
 is not present) wlstop : Not Available (the implementation class is
 not present) ddcreator : Not Available (the implementation class is
 not present) A task being missing/unavailable should only matter if
 you are trying to use it

 -------------------------------------------  org.apache.env.Which diagnostics
 ------------------------------------------- Not available. Download it at http://xml.apache.org/commons/

 -------------------------------------------  XML Parser information
 ------------------------------------------- XML Parser : com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl XML Parser
 Location: unknown Namespace-aware parser :
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
 Namespace-aware parser Location: unknown

 -------------------------------------------  XSLT Processor information
 ------------------------------------------- XSLT Processor : com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl XSLT
 Processor Location: unknown

 -------------------------------------------  System properties
 ------------------------------------------- java.runtime.name : Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment sun.boot.library.path :
 /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries
 java.vm.version : 20.4-b02-402 awt.nativeDoubleBuffering : true
 ant.library.dir : /Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib gopherProxySet :
 false mrj.build : 11M3527 java.vm.vendor : Apple Inc. java.vendor.url
 : http://www.apple.com/ path.separator : : java.vm.name : Java
 HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM file.encoding.pkg : sun.io user.country :
 US sun.java.launcher : SUN_STANDARD sun.os.patch.level : unknown
 java.vm.specification.name : Java Virtual Machine Specification
 user.dir : /Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant java.runtime.version :
 1.6.0_29-b11-402-11M3527 java.awt.graphicsenv : apple.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment java.endorsed.dirs :
 /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/endorsed
 os.arch : x86_64 java.io.tmpdir :
 /var/folders/l7/64z3f7sd77j9g_b7gwfbrqqh0000gn/T/ line.separator : 

 java.vm.specification.vendor : Sun Microsystems Inc. os.name : Mac OS
 X ant.home : /Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant sun.jnu.encoding :
 MacRoman java.library.path :
 .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
 java.specification.name : Java Platform API Specification
 java.class.version : 50.0 sun.management.compiler : HotSpot 64-Bit
 Tiered Compilers os.version : 10.7.2 http.nonProxyHosts :
 local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 user.home : /Users/alexanderfeil
 user.timezone : Europe/Berlin java.awt.printerjob :
 apple.awt.CPrinterJob java.specification.version : 1.6 file.encoding :
 MacRoman user.name : alexanderfeil java.class.path :
 /Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/.ant/lib/ant-commons-net-1.8.2.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-commons-net-1.8.2.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-jai.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-netrexx.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-swing.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant-testutil.jar:/Users/alexanderfeil/apache-ant/lib/ant.jar
 java.vm.specification.version : 1.0 sun.arch.data.model : 64 java.home
 : /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
 sun.java.command : org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -cp 
 -diagnostics java.specification.vendor : Sun Microsystems Inc. user.language : en awt.toolkit : apple.awt.CToolkit java.vm.info :
 mixed mode java.version : 1.6.0_29 java.ext.dirs :
 /Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext
 sun.boot.class.path :
 /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/jsfd.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Frameworks/JavaRuntimeSupport.framework/Resources/Java/JavaRuntimeSupport.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/ui.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/laf.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/sunrsasign.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/jsse.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/jce.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/charsets.jar
 java.vendor : Apple Inc. file.separator : / java.vendor.url.bug :
 http://bugreport.apple.com/ sun.cpu.endian : little
 sun.io.unicode.encoding : UnicodeLittle mrj.version :
 1070.1.6.0_29-402 socksNonProxyHosts : local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 jikes.class.path :
 :/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/../Classes/alt-rt.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/../Classes/alt-string.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/../Classes/charsets.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/../Classes/classes.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/../Classes/dt.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/../Classes/jce.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/../Classes/jconsole.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/../Classes/jsse.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/../Classes/management-agent.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/../Classes/ui.jar
 ftp.nonProxyHosts : local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
 sun.cpu.isalist : 

 -------------------------------------------  Temp dir
 ------------------------------------------- Temp dir is /var/folders/l7/64z3f7sd77j9g_b7gwfbrqqh0000gn/T/ Temp dir is
 writeable Temp dir alignment with system clock is -377 ms

 -------------------------------------------  Locale information
 ------------------------------------------- Timezone Central European Time offset=3600000

 -------------------------------------------  Proxy information
 ------------------------------------------- http.nonProxyHosts = "local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16" ftp.nonProxyHosts =
 "local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16" Java1.5+ proxy settings:
 Direct connection
```

Comment: please include the following in your question: the relevant parts from build.xml and the error you are getting. The mysql-jdbc-driver can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: for ftp you need jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar, I fixed that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SQL

You need to supply the jdbc driver for the sql task. Supply a `classpath` that points to your jdbc driver (which you probably downloaded from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/))

From the [Docs](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html):

```
<sql
    driver="org.database.jdbcDriver"
    url="jdbc:database-url"
    userid="sa"
    password="pass"
    src="data.sql"
    print="yes"
    output="outputfile.txt"
    >
<classpath>
    <pathelement location="/some/jdbc.jar"/>
</classpath>
</sql>
```

## FTP

You need `apache-commons-net-2.0.jar` and  `jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar` as listed  this [blogpost](http://projectfed.blogspot.com/2010/11/installing-ftp-task-on-ant-18x-on.html) and  [in the docs](https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar)(Although the doc says 1.4 should be enough)

Comment: still getting the "JDBC driver org.database.jdbcDriver could not be loaded" error.

Comment: @Abenil it has to be YOUR driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, I just pasted an example ;) Adapt it to your needs. The important part is the classpath. Or just put the jdbc driver into the lib folder.

Comment: ok....now it is working. or it is complaining about missing database name, but i can put it in the connection string....thank you so much. ;) but ftp is still not working.

Comment: @Abenil is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in the driver.jar?

Comment: yes...it is working now. thank you very much. ;) but ftp is still not working.

Comment: @Abenil try apache commons 2.0, as stated here: http://projectfed.blogspot.com/2010/11/installing-ftp-task-on-ant-18x-on.html, if it helps let me know.

Comment: thank you so much dude...i was fooling around with this for 10 hours. ;)